# Creating list of user defined objects throws The argument of type string cant be assigned to parameter type Phones

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to create a list of user defined objects. As in the snippet below it will be a list of Phone objects. When I am trying to add a String value to the list I get the error -
**The argument of type string cant be assigned to parameter type Phones**

```
void main() {
  List<Phones>? phones;
  phones.add('Test String'); -- ***Error is on this line***
}

class Contact {
  String? name;
  List<Phones>? phone;  
}

class Phones {
  String? phone;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<Phones>? phones;
```

Is as described a list of phones(object), Not of string

Make a constructor for your class to accept a String phone value

```
class Phones {
  String? phone;
  Phones(this.phone);
}
```

Then add the phone string this way

```
phones.add(Phones("Test String"));
```

You later can access the phone string like this

```
phones[index].phone
```